azure cache for redis - any logs during downtime?
We have an Azure Cache for redis instance in a dev envt. While prod will use a tier that supports high availability, we went with basic tier for the dev instance.
We had an outage a few weeks ago. For a window of 1 hour 10 minutes - 2:50 - 4:00 PM, redis was inaccessible to the development team. The application would fail to connect to redis with the following error message
StackExchange.Redis.RedisTimeoutException
Timeout awaiting response (outbound=0KiB, inbound=0KiB, 5432ms elapsed, timeout is 5000ms), command=HEXISTS, next: INFO, inst: 0, qu: 0, qs: 0, aw: False, bw: SpinningDown, rs: ReadAsync, ws: Idle, in: 0, last-in: 7721, cur-in: 0, sync-ops: 0, async-ops: 2202,

The redis instance too does not have any metrics for this duration, no used memory, connected clients, etc.

Nothing in activity logs either.
It looks like redis was down for an hour. It is on basic tier and there are no SLAs, and that's ok.
There isn't any information on why it was down for an hour. The documentation says patching takes a few seconds, so that may not be it.
We have not set scheduled maintenance window, so maybe maintenance took place at random time, but they could have placed a log somewhere.
Or, maybe there was a real down time. I just want to be able to get some event log like message that tells me what went wrong.
If a similar hiccup comes up in production, I would like to know where to quickly look, to get more info.
Any suggestions of any place to get the logs?

I also raised a ticket with Azure support. They investigated and concluded that it was "because the VMSS VM instance on which it was hosted unexpectedly went down without any action initiated by the Redis server. ... However, the cache is not expected to be down for such long duration, and we are working with infra team to find the root cause of it.". I haven't heard on why it was for over an hour.
It appears if there is an underlying infra issue there isn't any information available in azure monitor and needs a support ticket.

Check the Azure Activity Log for any events related to the Redis instance. This includes maintenance operations, reboots, or any changes that might have affected availability.

In the Azure portal, navigate to the Redis instance > Monitoring > Activity Log.

Enable Diagnostic Settings for the Redis instance. It allows you to collect logs and metrics into a Log Analytics workspace. Once the diagnostic settings are enabled, you can query the logs.
AzureActivity
| where ResourceId contains "Microsoft.Cache/Redis/your-cache-name"
| where TimeGenerated between(datetime(2024-04-29T14:50:00Z) .. datetime(2024-04-29T16:00:00Z))
| project TimeGenerated, OperationName, Status, EventInitiatedBy, ResourceId, Properties
| order by TimeGenerated desc

Log:
{
    "time": "2024-04-29T14:50:00Z",
    "operationName": "Update Redis Cache",
    "status": "Succeeded",
    "properties": {
        "resourceId": "/subscriptions/xxxx/resourceGroups/yyyy/providers/Microsoft.Cache/Redis/your-cache-name",
        "statusCode": "Accepted",
        "statusMessage": "The Redis Cache is undergoing maintenance.",
        "eventCategory": "Administrative",
        "operationId": "xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx",
        "correlationId": "xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx",
        "description": "Scheduled maintenance window."
    }
}


To monitor Redis metrics like connected clients and memory usage, you can use the following query:

InsightsMetrics
| where ResourceId contains "Microsoft.Cache/Redis/your-cache-name"
| where TimeGenerated between(datetime(2024-04-29T14:50:00Z) .. datetime(2024-04-29T16:00:00Z))
| where Name in ("connected_clients", "used_memory")
| project TimeGenerated, Name, Val
| order by TimeGenerated desc

During the downtime Logs:
{
    "time": "2024-04-29T14:50:00Z",
    "metricName": "connected_clients",
    "value": 0,
    "unit": "Count"
},
{
    "time": "2024-04-29T14:50:00Z",
    "metricName": "used_memory",
    "value": 0,
    "unit": "Bytes"
}

Configure alerts for critical metrics like connected clients, memory usage, and CPU usage. Alerts can notify immediately if there's an unexpected drop or spike.

It appears underlying infra issues leave no audit trail available to consumer (my comments under the question), your queries are useful in general, thanks.
